# iOS Dropdown Ajax

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, drop-down-menu

I’m new to the world of iOS development. 
I’m creating a iPad application where I need to have three dropdown (I know there is not dropdown on iOS, i'm doing a analogy with html).

The user selects the value from the first dropdown and the second will be loaded with respective values (from an external source). Then user selects one value from the second dropdown and the other dropdown will load values so the user can choose.

My question, if this was a web application I would use 3 dropdown Ajax, but on iPad applications there is no dropdown. What is the best controller to do this on a iPad application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use UITableview for that...you can take three table view or take only one tableview and set frame according to your requirement dynamically...then once you select any row from 1st table..using that value please fetch value for another table (for another drop down value list)....All The best!!

Comment: Probably I will use UITableview. Now I have to see what is the best way between 3 different UITableview or 1 UITableview that will load dynamic.... Thanks.

Comment: You Are Welcome ! I suggest that please handle it using single table & single array...For memory...

Answer (score 1):

iOS typically uses a combination of navigation controllers and table view controllers for this.  When the user selects an item in the table the entire things scrolls off the screen to reveal the next table ('menu').

You see this all the time in iPhone apps and in the master view of split view controllers on the iPad.

I'd recommend that you buy a book such as 'iPhone 4 development' to get you started.  There are many great books available.

Tim